# Laravel routing with conditions

Tags: php, laravel, routes, laravel-6

How does it(route:caching) work under hood and will it breake logic if I cached my routes.
I have a webhook which send me data to one single route. The data are difference only by objects fields. Will it correct to split it to different routes or I am need to make index method which will be redirect my logic by methods

```
Route::group(['namespace' => 'Webhook'], function () {

    if (Request::has('message')) {
        Route::post('/', 'WebhookController@message');
    }

    if (Request::has('callback_query')) {
        Route::post('/', 'WebhookController@callback');
    }

});
```

Comment: I wouldn't handle this in routes but in controller.

Comment: but how can I make validation via FormRequest ? If i will create From request in it this throw me an exception like ($request, should be an instance of Facade\Http\Request)
I have no idea how to validate it via FormRequest if index will be accept a Request 
```public function index(Request $request) {
 if($request->has('message')){
   return $this->message($request);
}
}

public function message(MessageRequest $request) {
 ...
}```

MessageRequest extends FromRequest and has custom rules

Comment: That's a different question. Consider opening another on that specific topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can shorten the routes code to this:

```
Route::group(['namespace' => 'Webhook'], function () {

    Route::post('/', 'WebhookController@handle');

});
```

And do the "heavy work" in the controller:

```
class WebhookController extends Controller
{
    public function handle(Request $request)
    {
        if ($request->has('message')) {
            return $this->message();
        }

        if ($request->has('callback_query')) {
            return $this->callback();
        }
    }

    public function message();

    public function callback(); 
}
```

This is equivalent to:

```
Route::group(['namespace' => 'Webhook'], function () {

    Route::post('/', function(Request $request) {
        if ($request->has('message')) {
            return (new WebhookController)->message();
        }

        if ($request->has('callback_query')) {
            return (new WebhookController)->callback();
        }
    });

});
```

Comment: Can you explain me why i shouldn't to pass this logic in my router?

Comment: It's not wrong in itself but to me it's more logical that since it's only on route really that this is shown by the routes.

Answer (score 0):

You can use middleware for such kind of logics.

[Laravel Middleware](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/middleware)

Comment: Instead of/additionally to a link could you add a code example?

Comment: `if ($request->input('token') !== 'my-secret-token') {
            return redirect('home');
}`     In middleware you can get the object data then you can redirect to desire routes

Comment: I have no idea how it will help me. just because if i will  redirect in middleware i will should use app(Controller::name)->$methodname($request) 
but it will throw an exception also

Comment: @SachchidaNandSharma You can add that to your answer. And if you don't mind taking an advice from me: I'd post some of the surrounding code alongside with it.

Comment: Can you explain me why such kind of logic should not be in to route?

Comment: Middleware can be written to perform a variety of tasks besides authentication. For example, a logging middleware might log all incoming requests to your application. Read Documentations Please.

Comment: I know about this. but I sure that it isn't best way to define route logic into middleware